# PHP Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I need a help on below, I know its raised in a past but I am currently struggling to figure it out the error Cannot use object of type stdClass as array on line

```
$score[$counter] = ($bronze * $tempArray[6]) + ($silver * $tempArray[5]) + ($silver * $tempArray[4]);
```

Code:

```
<?php
       //turning the date other way around that is why explode the date string and stored in an Array
    $gold=$_GET['gold_input'];
    $silver=$_GET['silver_input'];
    $bronze=$_GET['bronze_input'];
    $gdp_value=$_GET['gdp_checked'];
    $link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','coa123cdb');
    $myArray = array();
    //data format for information
//[{"name":"Ahmet Akdilek","country_name":"Turkey","gdp":"773091000000","population":"72752000"}
    $query = "SELECT  * FROM  coa123cdb.Country";

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query)
    or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($link));
    $row_cnt = $result->num_rows;
    if ($result = $link->query($query)) {
    $tempArray = array();
    $scorex=array($row_cnt);
    $score=(object)$scorex;
    $counter=0  ;
    //while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)){

      $tempArray = $row;
                if($gdp_value==0)
            {
            $score[$counter]=($bronze*$tempArray[6])+($silver*$tempArray[5])+($silver*$tempArray[4]);
            }
            else
            {$score[$counter]=($bronze*$tempArray[6]+$silver*$tempArray[5]+$silver*$tempArray[4])*$tempArray[1]/$tempArray[2]/10000;
            }
            array_push($tempArray, $score[$counter]);
            array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
                            $counter=$counter+1;
        }



        //var_dump($score);
    echo json_encode($myArray);
    }

    $result->close();
    $link->close();

  ?>
```

Comment: Why didn't you include the line?

Comment: I did below is the line I am getting an error on
$score[$counter]=($bronze*$tempArray[6])+($silver*$tempArray[5])+($silver*$tempArray[4]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at how you declared `$score`.

First you do `$scorex=array($row_cnt);` and then `$score=(object)$scorex;`.

So `$score` is cast to an object. However, in your code, you are still addressing it like an array, i.e. `$score[$counter]`. You should reference it as an object.

*EDIT*

Alternatively, update your definition for `$score` to the following:

```
 $score = array_fill (0, $row_cnt, 0);
```

This way, your assignment to `$score[$counter]` will still work (i think in the way you intended).

Comment: I modify as advised
$score[$counter]=($bronze*$tempArray->bronze)+($silver*$tempArray->silver)+($silver*$tempArray->gold);

but still getting the same error

Comment: I can't use mysql_fetch_object, I have to use mysqli_fetch_object or
$result->fetch_object() but on both getting the same error

Comment: take a look at how you declared `$score`. First you do `$scorex=array($row_cnt);` and then `$score=(object)$scorex;`. So `$score` is cast to an object. However, in your code, you are still addressing it like  an array, i.e. `$score[$counter]`. That also needs to change.

Comment: mysql_fetch_obj is deprecated, as are all the mysql_ functions - mysqli_fetch_obj is not.

Comment: @ryan...thanks for your reply, but do you mind please telling us how can I change this to make it working

Comment: I updated the definition but still no joy. please if its possible how can I refer this as an object?

Comment: It's possible, but you'd initialize the object with a property for each of the indexes you wish to use, and then update your code to refer to them properly, e.g. `$score->{'0'}`.

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_fetch_object` returns an object.

So after the line `$row=mysqli_fetch_object($result)` is an object.

If you want an array use `mysqli_fetch_array` instead.

And before using that array check its contents with `var_dump($row);` (to prevent further questions).